# Windows path no longer shows as list in Control Panel Environment Variables

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables, path, control-panel

When I manage my environment variables from the Control Panel (System > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables), PATH used to show up as a nice, manageable list of folders which were easy to rearrange, as illustrated [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/), for instance.

Now, for some unknown reason, it only shows as any other variable, i.e. a simple, long, semi-colon-separated string of folders:

[image: Imgur]

Does anyone know what happened and how I can fix this?

Comment: You may want to include some screenshots of the differences you're talking about. But to be clear, at least as far as I am aware, the basic presentation of PATH variables (i.e. as a long semicolon list) has never changed. They are only presented as a list when they are being edited.

Comment: Note that the links presented under Windows Search will also take you to different places. One will take you to the general list of environment variables (as semicolon separated lists) and the other will take you directly to the editor for your e.g. PATH variable (i.e. presented as a list).

Answer (score 3):

It turned out to be a pretty nasty twist. The path was perfectly valid and working. However, the first entry started with another environment variable (containing a base folder location). Once I moved it after a first, fully explicit value, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

It's because the value is invalid and can't be formatted properly in the list.

Check that the items are separated with `;` additionally, you should have a leading `;` at the end of the variable. You can trim the value until you hit the point where the Path is formatted as a list again.

If you can't find the error in your Path, show us the actual value.